# Finding unique group of rows in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping

I have a data frame where I want to compare group of rows and remove only if the entire group is same. For example:

```
df<-data.frame(X=c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"), Y=c(1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,1), Z=c("ABC","DEF","ABC", "DEF", "DEF", "DEF", "ABC", "DEF", "ABC"))

  X Y   Z
1 a 1 ABC
2 a 2 DEF
3 a 1 ABC
4 b 2 DEF
5 b 2 DEF
6 b 2 DEF
7 c 1 ABC
8 c 2 DEF
9 c 1 ABC
```

Here group is identified by column X and I want to compare among different groups. So, Here group a and group c are identical. I want to get the final desired result as below:

```
  GroupID Y   Z
1 1       1 ABC
2 1       2 DEF
3 1       1 ABC
4 2       2 DEF
5 2       2 DEF
6 2       2 DEF
```

Any idea how can I do this kind of compare?

Comment: So, df <- df[!duplicated(df),] ?

Comment: @OliverKeyes That will remove row by row and in that case it will return 5 rows. In the expected answer above, there are 6 rows.

Comment: So, you're looking to, for each unique value of X, retrieve distinct (Y,Z) tuples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `base` R possibility:

```
# For each 'X', collapse 'Y' and 'Z' to a vector
l <- by(df[ , c("Y", "Z")], df$X, function(dat) paste0(dat, collapse = ""))

# select names of unique list elements
nm <- names(l)[!duplicated(l)]

# use these names to subset the data frame
df[df$X %in% nm, ]
#   X Y   Z
# 1 a 1 ABC
# 2 a 2 DEF
# 3 a 1 ABC
# 4 b 2 DEF
# 5 b 2 DEF
# 6 b 2 DEF
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need to look into the `compare` function from the "compare" package. Here's a possibility:

```
library(compare)
x <- with(df, split(df[-1], df[[1]]))
Splits <- combn(names(x), 2)
Comparison <- apply(Splits, 2, function(y) {
  compare(x[y[1]], x[y[2]], allowAll = TRUE)$result
})
Splits[, Comparison]
# [1] "a" "c"
```

From this we can see that groups "a" and "c" are duplicated, and we can use that to subset the original dataset.

---

I've used `allowAll = TRUE` in this answer, but you may want to look at the other options available in `compare` to decide what transformations you would actually want to allow in your comparisons.

Comment: My data frame is slightly different than what showed in the question above. When I print `compare` output. I get the following result: `FALSE [TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE]` Individual column comparison is fine (showing all TRUE) but I don't understand why result is `FALSE`. Any idea?